# Find the most frequent entry in a file using unix

Tags: file, unix, gnuplot

I have a file containing around 2,000,000 entries - just one column with that many entries, all numbers. I would like to quickly find out what the most frequent number in the file is.. Is there a way to do this using unix?
I know how to do it using gnuplot but it is a slightly tedious way and was wondering if there was a simpler way just by using some unix commands?
Like if my file is

```
1
1
1
2
3
4
```

Then I want it to read the file and give me the answer 1 because thats the most frequent.

Comment: You could write a really simple C utility to do this for you. Hash map entries, add them up as you go.  O(N) algorithm.  N = number of entries.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution using command line as your question title implies, or do you accept a program in C, as your tag says but don't mention this option in your question?

Comment: is the file in ascending order like your example? And how long are the numbers? As well are some negative or floating point?

Comment: @LostAvatar I'm sorry I've taken the c tag down, my file was just generated by a c program.. Sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ cat file|sort -n|uniq -c|sort -n|tail -n 1|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: That will output the number of occurences for each number, but it won't filter out the number with the most occurences.

Comment: Yeah thats fine for me, because in my file theres only a few numbers that have very high occurences I can differentiate very quickly myself. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 1` should help. It prints the number of occurences and the number that is most used, so for your example file it would be: `3 1`

Answer (score 0):

My first answer to that would be building an histogram. It helps if the range of possible values is small enough.

Once the histogram is built, just look for the highest amount in it.

Comment: Yeah I already have a histogram but it doesn't give me the exact value just round about.. thats what I meant by it being tedious in gnuplot I'd have to do the histogram and set a table to save all the frequencies in a file blah blah blah.. but thanks!